# A control must be associated with a text label

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, airbnb-js-styleguide

I am getting the error:

> A control must be associated with a text label.

The piece of code is:

```
 <i
   role="button"
   className={classN}
   onClick={this.muteVolume}
   onKeyDown={this.muteVolume}
 />
```

That error is related to [this eslint rule](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/label-has-associated-control.md).

That rule makes sense when using a label and a control associated. In my case, I do not need a label at all. I could create one but that looks to me like a workaround to avoid getting that error.

What is the problem?

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @rickdenhaan, the correct rule to apply is [this one](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/control-has-associated-label.md).

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error in codesandbox, without success. are you using create-react-app?

Comment: Hi Stamatis, I did use create-react-app. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

That message actually comes from the [control-has-associated-label](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/control-has-associated-label.md) rule.

The rule is triggered by the `role="button"` attribute. That turns your `<i />` into a control, so it needs a text label for accessibility reasons (so screen readers know what to read out, for example). To comply with the rule, you can either give the "button" textual content or add an `aria-label` attribute:

```
<i
   role="button"
   className={classN}
   onClick={this.muteVolume}
   onKeyDown={this.muteVolume}
>
  Mute volume
</i>

<i
   role="button"
   aria-label="Mute volume"
   className={classN}
   onClick={this.muteVolume}
   onKeyDown={this.muteVolume}
 />
```

Comment: Hi rickdenhaan,

You are right. The error "A control must be associated with a text label" may be a bit confusing between those two rules. Thank you for your time.

My solution was to add "aria-label" attribute by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error. My use case was this:
[image]

I disabled this error and the web-app was still functioning well. I basically disabled eslint for the line where error was being throwed by inserting this before the line:

```
{/* eslint-disable-next-line */}
```

So the error-free code then looks like:
[image]

It is a .jsx file by the way. Hope it helps :)